# Office Open XML - Target Cell by its content

Tags: c#, .net, xlsx

How to target Cell if I know its content (there are no duplicates in the xlsx document) using Office Open XML?

I mean I have xlsx sheet (template) and somewhere in it placed my "variable". For example "<<_time>>". I want to find that element (by "variable" name) and change the cell value (current time in this case).

Basic code:

```
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"...");
        FileInfo template = new FileInfo(@"...");

        using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile, template))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

            //need target Cell by it's value (must use for-loop?)
            //worksheet.Cells[...].Value = "...";


            xlPackage.Save();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by classic loop.

```
            var start = worksheet.Dimension.Start;
            var end = worksheet.Dimension.End;

            for (int row = start.Row; row <= end.Row; row++)
            {
                for (int col = start.Column; col <= end.Column; col++)
                {
                    string cellValue = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text.ToString();
                    if (cellValue == "<<_time>>")
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value = "..";
                    }
                }
            }
```